# Spring bean lazy initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-bean

I was thinking about the lazy-initialization of beans in Spring. For me, it wasn't crystal clear that the "lazy" here means that a bean will be created when it's referenced.

I expected that the lazy initialization support in Spring is different. I thought this is a "method-call" based lazy creation. What I mean by this is, whenever any method is being called on the method, it will be created.

I think this could be easily solved by creating a proxy instance of the specific bean and do the initialization on any method call.

Am I missing something why this is not implemented? Is there any problem with this concept?

Any feedback/idea/answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve the behavior you want by scoping your bean with a `proxyMode` of `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` (CGLIB) or `ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES` (JDK).

For example

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Conf.class);
        Bar bar = ctx.getBean(Bar.class);
        System.out.println(bar);
        System.out.println(bar.foo.toString());
    }
}

@Configuration
class Conf {
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    @Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Foo foo() {
        System.out.println("heyy");
        return new Foo();
    }

    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar();
    }
}

class Bar {
    @Autowired
    public Foo foo;
}

class Foo {
}
```

will print

```
com.example.Bar@3a52dba3
heyy
com.example.Foo@7bedc48a
```

demonstrating that the `Foo` bean was initialized through its `@Bean` factory method only after a method was invoked on the `Foo` instance injected by the Spring context in the `Bar` bean.

The `@Scope` annotation can be used in a class declaration as well.

Comment: Do you know how to make lazy-load of beans like this? "return FactoryProvider().getFactory()"

Answer (score -1):

bellow is my views:

> Bean types in Spring Container:

There are two **Scope** bean type in **Spring Container**.One is **Prototype**, this type bean won't exist **lazy-init** concept, because these beans will be instantiated when clients invoke the **getBean()** method **every time**. Another is **Singleton**, these bean will be instantiated **once**, these beans can be lazily instantiated(**just be instantiated** when they're used, such as @Autowired, refrenced) if you define the bean use **@Lazy** or **lazy-init=true**.

> How to implement **lazy-init**:

Yes, common implementation is **Proxy Mode**. Spring use **JDK Dynamic Proxy** and **Cglib** to implement **Proxy**, you can go further understanding about these techs.

Hope to help you.